# How to add page break between file documents in master document libreoffice writer?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I have created master document in libreoffice and added some subdocuments (odt) and I need to put page break between them. Every new document needs to start with new page. I have found some answers on forum but there are not very clear. Thanks in advance!

[image]

1. Before this I used different page style, so I used manual break to use different page style for rest of document. I need to remove this enter tag, if I delete it, it deletes a manual page break.
2. I need to add page break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answer at [ask.libreoffice.org](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-to-add-page-break-between-file-documents-in-master-document-libreoffice-writer/68458) and I think it is worth of share.

> If your sub-documents represent chapters in your book, you have a much
> more elegant solution than adding manually page breaks in the master.
>
> I assume that your files are all styled (which is a necessity when
> working with master + subs otherwise formatting becomes a nightmare)
> and you assigned Heading 1 to the chapter headings.
>
> Then customize Heading 1 in the master to add a page break (before) in
> the Text Flow tab properties.
>
> An even better approach is to share all styles between master and subs
> with a personal template. Master and subs should be based on this
> template. A template brings in the possibility to automatically update
> formatting of all documents: change the style definition in the
> template; next time you open a document, you’re asked if you accept
> the update.